# Install WiFi Driver for Zero W without WiFi-Connectoin

Tags: wifi, driver, image

I have this customized Raspbian Image, which I need to operate a DIY Hardware solution. The Image is configured for a Raspberry Pi 2 B+. I now want to use the Image for a Raspberry Pi Zero W. With this image unfortunately, I cannot configure the Pi Zero to connect to my WiFi. I think, this is because of missing WiFi drivers. I need a way to install these drivers working through the SD card. I have a secondary operating Linux System by my side, so I try to copy+paste the according driver to the appropriate position. Can someone guide me through this process?

Thanks a lot.
Best,
Hellma

Comment: You could use `qemu` and `chroot` to accees your sd-card and install something on it. [This script worked for me](https://gist.github.com/htruong/7df502fb60268eeee5bca21ef3e436eb).

Comment: have you considered changing the image where it does work?

Comment: Ok, so what I did now was what @Jaromanda suggested. I built everything from scratch. The problem was a proprietary driver for the new Pi Zero W chipset.